# Create issues in JIRA as anonymous but with assignee to track his status

Tags: python, apache, authentication, single-sign-on, jira-rest-api

I am trying to use jira rest api to create issues in python flask. I am using sspi authentication with apache server and getting user details from ldap with windows logged in Id(Here I don't get password).

Earlier I am creating issues in JIRA as anonymously due to this, the user is not able to track the issue status. Now I want authenticate JIRA or Is there any way to sent reporter in payload so that he can be updated with status emails automatically.

It would be very much appreciated for suggestions and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As the question says assignee but the description requires reporter, you can pass `reporter` and `assignee` in the request body inside `field` of [Create issue REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/#api-api-2-issue-post) just like this

```
{
  "fields": {
    "summary": "this is a test summary",
    "project": {
      "key": "TEST"
    },
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Story"
    },
    "reporter": {
      "name": "ian"
    },
    "assignee": {
      "name": "admin"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick response. You are saying that,  even with anonymous authentication we can pass reporter so that he will get triggered mails for status change.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "anonymous authentication", but if you're already able to create an issue via REST API, passing the reporter as a parameter should work.

Comment: Ok Thanks, anonymous means. I am not authenticating JIRA with Basic or oath. K let me try.